# How to enable the ftp module in php "Call to undefined function ftp_connect()"

Tags: php, yocto, vsftpd

I'm pretty new to Yocto, and I'm trying to call the **ftp_connect**() function within my php, but get an undefined function error.

I'm using Yocto Poky kirkstone (4.0.2) for corei7-64-poky-linux, and in my local.conf file I added the following:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL:append = " lighttpd lighttpd-module-fastcgi"
IMAGE_INSTALL:append = " vsftpd"
IMAGE_INSTALL:append = " php php-fpm"
PACKAGECONFIG[php] = " --enable-ftp --enable-debug "
```

I created a lighttpd_%.bbappend to customised lighttpd.conf with the right "server.document-root", "mod_fastcgi" and "fastcgi.server".

My webpage is loading and php 8.1.8 is working, but the ftp module is not loaded!

phpinfo() doesn't show the "**--enable-ftp**" option,

And no php.ini file is loaded:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   /etc/php/apache2-php8
Loaded Configuration File   (none)
```

Why does it show apache2 when i'm using lighttpd? And why no ini file is loaded?
And more importantly how do i enable ftp for PHP?

I tried to add apache2 to my local.conf, and adding "extension=ftp" using the following **php_%.bbappend**, but this didn't work either!

```
PHP_MAJOR_VERSION = "${@d.getVar('PV').split('.')[0]}"


do_install:append:class-target() {
    echo "extension=ftp" >>  ${D}${sysconfdir}/php/apache2-php${PHP_MAJOR_VERSION}/php.ini  
}
```

I tried to add some debug line as follow but this didn't help:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
ini_set("log_errors", 1);  //
ini_set("error_log", "/tmp/php-error.log");
error_log( "Hello, errors!" );
```

Thanks in advance for your help, I've been trying for days now.

Comment: Which version of Yocto are you using ? ( https://wiki.yoctoproject.org/wiki/Releases ). Which php version are you trying to integrate ?

Comment: Hi Martin, I'm using yocto DISTRO_VERSION = "4.0.2" DISTRO_CODENAME = "kirkstone", and PHP 8.1.8.  I have now edited my question with those information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's the right way, but I finally managed to make it work.

I just needed to add php-fpm in my local.conf

> IMAGE_INSTALL:append = " php-fpm"

And to create a php_%.bbappend with the following:

> EXTRA_OECONF += " --enable-ftp"